# How to write to a file with one instance of new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter()); in different methods

Tags: java, file-io, io

Because  the `BufferWritter` is within a try catch block I cannot use the same instance in a seperate method without creating a new file. I dont want to read from the file and modify the information as this may clash with future development of this program.

**So my question is how can I write to the same file without creating a new instance of `BufferWritter`**.

```
private void writeStudentInfo(){

    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    try {       
         writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:/" +                                                
             this.getStudentRegistrationNumber() + ".txt", true));

             // Write to file here

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    } finally {
        if (writer != null) {
            try {
                writer.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Second Method:**

```
private void WriteStudentMarks(){

    //I want to use the same instance of BufferWritter in this method for writtng.
    // So I can use the 'writer' object to continue writting into the file.

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simply pass the reference to the writer to each method, for example...

```
private void WriteStudentMarks(BufferedWriter writer){
```

Then simply call the method

```
BufferedWriter writer = null;
//...
WriteStudentMarks(writer); 
//...
```

You may, also, wish to have read through [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html), it will make it eaiser for people to read your code...

Comment: but then every time I pass the WriteStudentMakrs(writer) method  I will be creating a new instance of BufferedWriter() because a new instance is included in the WriteStudentMarks() Method. this will create a new file every time I call the method into another method when I only want to create one file, adding to the file as I call the method into each other method

Comment: No, you won't.  You create a single instance in your `writeStudentInfo` and simply pass a "pointer" to that instance to each method.  If I give you an ice cream, does it create a new instance of the ice cream? (I wish it did...)

Comment: Im failing to understand how I will write using the `WriteStudentMarks(writer);` method inside another method if that method has objects I want to write into the `BufferWritter` object in the `WriteStudentInfo()` method.

Comment: Well, presumably, you would need to pass what you want written to that method as well...

Comment: Yes but I will need a seperate `WriteStudentInfo()` for each different method, taking different parameters because I am writing different information in different methods.   For example `WriteStudentMarks(int examMaths, ExamEnglish)`    then in another method `writeStudentPersonalInfo(String firstName, String SecondName,   int student registration)` And this will mean creating new instances of `BufferedWritter`

Comment: If I have to create two different methods `writeStudentPersonalInfo(String firstName, String SecondName, int student registration)` and `WriteStudentMarks(int examMaths, ExamEnglish)`  both that include a new instance of `bufferedWritter` then wont I be creating 2 sepereate files when I only want one file to be created?

Comment: No. It will only create a single file, because that's what you did in the parent method.  The other methods will simply use the reference to the `writer` you pass them to write information.  They won't care if it's writing to a file, socket or some other dimension...